# Access Mahapps.Metro-icons through code

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I'm trying to figure out a way to change a borders visual brush during runtime, and set the visual to a Mahapps.Metro icon.

Here's what the border looks like in XAML:

```
<Border Height="24" Width="24" Margin="12,2,0,12" Background="#585858">
                        <Border.OpacityMask>
                            <VisualBrush Visual="{StaticResource appbar_star}" Stretch="Fill" />
                        </Border.OpacityMask>
</Border>
```

As default I have the Visual to be of the "StaticResource appbar_star"
But How would I do

```
 Border.Opacitymask = VisualBrush() { Visual = (Visual)ICONNAME };
```

I have no idea how to access the icons during runtime. Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you manipulating the UI thru procedural code to begin with?

Comment: @HighCore Not that skilled with WPF yet. But I was planning on making a converter based on objects' values.

Comment: This border is inside a ListviewItemtempate btw.

Comment: It would seem to me that would be easier with a `DataTrigger` or the like. Can you post a little more detail of what data are you trying to convert and what logic are you using?

Comment: I have a Listview which among few has an int value called Mode. The Mode can either be 0 , 1 or 2. If 0, I want the border's Visualbrush to be an icon. 1 = another icon, and 2 = another icon. But you're right. I will try to use the DataTrigger.

Answer (score 0):

To access resources you can use:

```
var resource = System.Windows.Application.Current.FindResource(key);
```

You can go step forward and create a converter that will map resource keys to resources, to achieve xaml like this:

```
<VisualBrush Visual="{Binding IconKey,Converter={local:KeyToResourceConverter}}" />
```

you can create converter like this:

```
public class KeyToResourceConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return System.Windows.Application.Current.FindResource(value as string);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

What I personally don't like in such solution is an indirect dependency of ViewModel on View through view related keys, e.g. to change visual style you will have to change a ViewModel.

If you can make Mode a class then it's possible to use DataTemplates, consider next setup:

ViewModel:

```
interface IMode { }

class FirstMode:IMode { }

class SecondMode : IMode { }

class ThirdMode : IMode { }

class ViewModel
{
    public IMode Mode { get; private set; }
}
```

View:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:FirstMode}">
    <Border>
        <Border.OpacityMask>
            <VisualBrush Visual="{StaticResource appbar_star}" Stretch="Fill" />
        </Border.OpacityMask>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SecondMode}">
    <Border>
        <Border.OpacityMask>
            <VisualBrush Visual="{StaticResource appbar_control_stop}" Stretch="Fill" />
        </Border.OpacityMask>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ThirdMode}">
    <Border>
        <Border.OpacityMask>
            <VisualBrush Visual="{StaticResource appbar_control_pause}" Stretch="Fill" />
        </Border.OpacityMask>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModel}">
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Mode}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```